# What's the use of parentheses `()` in shell function definition?

Tags: bash

A function is defined as:

```
do_something () {
    do it
}
```

I could understand its name 'do_something' and the curly bracket to encapsulate the actions code, but am unable to get the idea what's the purpose of `()` here, since there are no named parameters in Bash scripts. It might be better and straightforward to define it as

```
do_something {
  do it
}
```

Which does not conflict with its current syntax, and even more declares that there are no named parameters. What's the usage of `()` here?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo

Comment: A function definition is `do_something () any-command` in the Bourne shell and most Bourne-like shells (`bash` being the most notable exception) and `do_something () any-compound-command` in all POSIX shells (including `bash`). That `any-command`/`any-compound-command` does not have to be the `{ command-group; }` compound command, it can by any other type of compound command including `(subshell)`, `for`/`while`/`if` statements or in Korn-like shells (including `bash`) `[[...]]`, `((...))`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### Without the `()`, the syntax really would be ambiguous.

There has to be *some* unambiguous syntax for defining a function, and without substantially altering *other* shell syntax, it cannot be this:

```
do_something {
    # one or more commands go here
}
```

You said this "does not confict with its current syntax," but it does! Notice that you do not get any kind of syntax error when you try to run *the first line of that*. You get an error, but it is not an error about syntax. The second line, with `}`, is a syntax error, but the first line is not. Instead, `do_something {` attempts to run a command called `do_something` and pass `{` as an argument to that command:

```
$ do_something {
do_something: command not found
```

If there is already a command called `do_something`, you are running it. If there is already a function called `do_something`, *you are calling it*. It's important in general that syntax be unambiguous, but it is also important specifically that it be possible to redefine a function without accidentally calling it instead. Defining a function and calling it should not look the same.

#### How the shell treats `{` and `(`.

As `type {` will tell you, `{` is a shell keyword. This makes it like `[[`. If used in a situation where it would otherwise be a command, `{` carries special semantics. Specifically, it performs command grouping. In other situations, however, it may be used unescaped to denote a literal `{` character. This includes the situation of passing it as a second or subsequent word of a command.

Of course, Bash *could* have been designed to treat `{` differently than it currently does. However, its syntax would then no longer have been compatible with the POSIX shell, and Bash would not really be a Bourne-style shell and would not be capable of running many shell scripts.

In contrast, `(` is a shell metacharacter. It is always treated specially if it appears in a command and is not quoted (with `'` `'`, `"` `"`, or `\`). There is thus no ambiguity in the syntax:

```
do_something() {
    # one or more commands go here
}
```

That couldn't mean anything else. If Bash didn't have functions, then it would be a syntax error, for the same reason `echo foo(bar)` is a syntax error.

If you really dislike the `()` notation then you can use the keyword `function` and omit it, as [sudodus mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023947/22949). Note that this is *not* part of the syntax for defining functions in most other Bourne-style shells--and in some, it is supported but functions defined that way have [different semantics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73854/11938)--and so a script that uses it will not be portable. (The reason this syntax is able to be unambiguous is that `function` is itself a keyword in Bash that signifies that whatever follows it is the start of a function definition.)

Finally, note that while most function definitions use `{` in practice, any compound command is permitted. If you had a function whose body you wanted always to run in a subshell, you could use `(` `)` rather than `{` `}`.

Comment: At a higher level, it's about human expectations and readability.  In most languages, particularly in C, fortran, and others common around the time the bash scripting languages was developed, a function/subroutine always has an argument list, possibly empty, that's enclosed in parentheses.  Change that paradigm, and you make it harder to understand the language.

Comment: I got another issue, with the following function: `function gsq {
    git reset --hard HEAD~5;
    git merge --squash HEAD@ { 1 };
    git commit
}` How can I make it work with the braces inside? Should I post a question?

Comment: @Timo You should probably post a question, but my *guess* is that the problems are: *(a)* `HEAD@ { 1 }` needs to be `HEAD@{1}` with no spaces around the braces (unrelated to it being in a function) and *(b)* if the final `}` intended to end the function definition is not preceded by a newline (I can't tell, as comments often appear with different formatting than desired) then it must be preceded by a `;`, since otherwise it is taken to be an argument to the command that comes before it (`git commit }` has the same issue as `do_something {`) and the compound command is never actually finished.

Comment: @Eliah, This sounds plausible, will try it. I often read your post, and the last paragraph is maybe also an option. But I do not want a **subshell**

Answer (score 17):

The `()` token is to tell the shell interpreter that you are declaring a function.

```
$ do_something () { echo 'do it'; } ; do_something
do it
```

An alternative in `bash` is `function`

```
function do_something {
 echo 'do it'
}
```

or as a one-liner you can test

```
$ bash -c "function do_something { echo 'do it'; } ; do_something"
do it
```

Comment: The `function` keyword is a pre-POSIX ksh-ism that bash supports for backwards compatibility; however, bash supports it *badly* (not making variables function-local default, as old ksh did in functions declared in that form). Consequently, it's not ideal for new code. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for this explanation :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Are you saying ksh and bash accept some syntax that makes a variable local in ksh but global in bash? That doesn't sound right. My understanding, based partly on [that post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73854) and [checking](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zcT73fRjWv/) (in ksh93), is that ksh makes variables local in *fewer* situations than bash, never more. In bash, `typeset` without `-g` in a function always declares a local variable. With the `function` keyword, bash and ksh scope variables *the same way*, do they not?

Comment: @EliahKagan I think what Charles has been referring to has been demonstrated in [Gille's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73854/85039) here

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sadly that link has expired and the domain is now up for sale :(

Answer (score 9):

How very [one-true-brace-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style)-ist of you!

Consider other, perfectly fine brace styles:

```
foo
{
  ...
}
foo
  {
    ...
  }
foo
  while ...; do ...; done # Look, ma! No braces!
foo
( ... ) # Look, ma! No braces and a subshell to boot!
```

How can the shell tell that those are function definitions and not simply a command `foo` followed by command lists? In all these cases, an additional disambiguating factor, like `()` or the `function` keyword is necessary.

Comment: On second thought, that's not actually OTBS, since the one place where OTBS allows braces on a new line is for function definitions.

Comment: I think there's an argument to be made that you were right to characterize it as OTBS, because unlike functions in C and C++, a function definition in a Bourne-style shell script can be nested *directly* in the body of another function definition and so arguably doesn't deserve to be distinguished. (Or maybe this is the style popular in Java programming where methods get their opening brace on the same line, rather than OTBS.) Either way, you make an excellent point about how the syntax would have to impose tight constraints on brace placement to work at all without `()` or something like it.