# (First C Program / Hello World) Keep getting Syntax Error

Tags: c

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hello() {
    printf("Hello n10321234, welcome to BSB211");
}

int main() {
    print_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I keep getting the following errors when I compile and run the executable.

```
./print_hello: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token ('

./print_hello: line 3: `void print_hello(){'
```

For compiling, I use `gcc print_hello.c -o print_hello` 
and to run I use `./print_hello`.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. There seems to be no obvious error in your code above. But please note that your question is much more suitable for https://stackoverflow.com/ . You should also include some information on how you compile your code ...

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are using, but on Ubuntu c programs get compiled to *executable* binaries and not .exe files.  Your question is off-topic as written https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Usually too the compile and execution/run steps are separated, compile errors occurring at compile time, link step follows then a later step actually executes the code; your wording implies both *compile* and *execute* are done together so you didn't mention what tool as it doesn't sound like `gcc` or `clang` so you should be specific.

Comment: Ah okay, Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: you sure you are not executing the source instead

Comment: I just built it and executed on Ubuntu 16.04, it runs well.

Comment: Reviewers: This isn't really off-topic. It's not about how to write C++ code. It's a tooling question and it's OS-specific (at least the form it takes is OS-specific, and in practice the confusion here isn't one people face in some popular OSes, e.g., Windows). We have some questions that cover this. I think we should reopen this and close it as a duplicate of one of them, perhaps [Why do I get syntax error when I try to run my C++ program after compiling it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024721/22949) (Per the [help/on-topic], "Development on Ubuntu" is on-topic. That has to include *something*.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get syntax error when I try to run my C++ program after compiling it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024721/why-do-i-get-syntax-error-when-i-try-to-run-my-c-program-after-compiling-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to "execute" the source code instead of the binary file produced by the C compiler & linker.

Please:

1. Go to the directory containing your C program.
2. Remove file *print_hello* using command: `rm -f print_hello`.
3. Correct the permissions of *print_hello.c* file using command: `chmod 640 print_hello.c`
4. Run the command: `gcc print_hello.c -o print_hello` and ensure that it does ***not*** output any error message.
5. Ensure that a new executable is created in the current directory by checking the output of the command: `file print_hello`.
6. Run the new executable using the command: `./print_hello`.

Note: After you edit (change) your source code, just re-run steps 4 and 6.

Comment: How should this help on the syntax-error ?

Comment: The OP is trying the "execute" the source code instead of the binary file produced by the C compiler & linker. I assume that these precise steps will help the OP avoid such pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your source code was written or edited in a non-Unix environment and you try to compile it in Ubuntu.

The error message syntax error near unexpected token `(‘ occurs in a Unix-type environment, Cygwin, and in the command-line interface in Windows. This error will most probably be triggered when you try to run a shell script which was edited or created in older DOS/Windows or Mac systems.

In such case you can use [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) tool to convert it.

```
 dos2unix yoursourcecode.c
```

For more info : https://appuals.com/fix-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token/